# Can't change km to miles in distancematrix service (google map)?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
service.getDistanceMatrix({
  origins: [source],
  destinations: [destination],
  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
  unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
  avoidHighways: false,
  avoidTolls: false
})
```

I'm using this code to change the units from kilometers to miles but it doesn't work.
I have to connect to area using google map. I have to show distance in miles.

Comment: Where is the distance being displayed in km?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.  The "unitSystem" just controls the text of the distance in the response, the value is always meters (but there is a formula to convert that to miles): `distance: The total distance of this route, expressed in meters (value) and as text. The textual value is formatted according to the unitSystem specified in the request (or in metric, if no preference was supplied).`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Google Docs on the Distance interface](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/directions#Distance) (see screenshot below), the `value` property is always displayed in meters. Only the `text` property uses the unit system specified in the request.

[image: distance interface]